# How to Run iOS application to device from Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e) withough cable(Via WIFI - Bluetooth)?

Tags: ios, debugging, ios8, xcode6

I m goggling the things from few days about the debugging the iPhone application from `Xcode(Version 6.2 (6C131e))` without using cable.

i have heard that OS X Yosemite of MAC have feature that can connect iPhone to Mac without cable.if is it so,than is anybody have any idea that how to build project into device from XCode without cable `(Wi-Fi / Bluetooth)`?.

is there any way to workaround to build or debug project in to device without using cable?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has not specified how to build an Application on a device which is not connected through cable. If they do so in future, external ascessory, Multipeer connectivity framework (for WiFi) and CoreBluetooth Peripheral Manager (for bluetooth) will certainly come into account but before that, will Bluetooth or WiFi streaming  withstand the code transfer load from Xcode to a device? And what if you device is already connected to some other WiFi or Bluetooth network?

Answer (score 1):

This is now a reality!  With Xcode 9 and iOS 11 you can now perform wireless builds to a device.